# simple show and hide elements with parent next

Tags: jquery, loops, show

i would like to hide the parent div and show the next div of the parent parent ( same class ).

```
<div class="collections">
<div class="switchswitch"> 
<span>title</span>
<span class="switch middle">
<img class="wp-post-image" src="image.jpg">
</span>
</div>

<div class="switchswitch"> 
<span>title</span>
<span class="switch middle">
<img class="wp-post-image" src="image.jpg">
</span>
</div>

<div class="switchswitch"> 
<span>title</span>
<span class="switch middle">
<img class="wp-post-image" src="image.jpg">
</span>
</div>

</div>
```

...the css:

```
.switchswitch {
    display: none;
}
.selected{
    display: block;
}
```

...and the js:

```
$('.wp-post-image').click(function(){
    var $next = $('.switchswitch').removeClass('selected').parent('.collections').next('.section')
    if ($next.length) {
    $next.addClass('selected'); 
    }
    else {
        $(".switchswitch:first").addClass('selected');
    }
});
```

it should be a loop, and everytime i click the image with the class "wp-post-image" the parent div "switchswitch" shoud be hidden and the next "switchswitch" should show up..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$('.wp-post-image').click(function() {
                var $next = $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('selected').next('.switchswitch');
                    if ($next.length) {
                        $next.addClass('selected');
                    }
                    else {
                        $(".switchswitch:first").addClass('selected');
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('.wp-post-image').click(function(){
    var $next = $(this).closest('.switchswitch').removeClass('selected').closest('.collections').next().find('.switchswitch')
    if ($next.length) {
    $next.addClass('selected'); 
    }
    else {
        $(".switchswitch:first").addClass('selected');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The original script was traversing up to the `.collections` element and then searching for the next `.section` which doesn't exist in the markup.

**Javascript**

```
$('.wp-post-image').click(function(){
    var $curSection = $(this).closest(".switchswitch");        
    $curSection.removeClass('selected');
    var $next =  $curSection.next(".switchswitch");
    if ($next.length) {
        $next.addClass('selected'); 
    }
    else {
        $(".switchswitch:first").addClass('selected');
    }
});
```

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/GJp3k/

Comment: THX @kevin!
it works fine, but with multiple "slideshows" ( multiple collections ) it doesn't works. here the update: http://jsfiddle.net/GJp3k/1/

Comment: i think it needs really a "parent" function, that only uses its child elements "switchswitch".. any idea?